# Laravel: the time for job queue

Tags: php, laravel-5

With Laravel, I would like to make a job queue **each 3 months** ! So I would like to check.

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->monthly()->monthly()->monthly()->when(function () {
    return true;
});
```

Can I write like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `monthly()` three time won't work.

You will have to use crontab syntax to make a job run 'every three month'

Something like:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->cron('* * * */3');
```

Double check the crontab entry with online tools such as [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Comment: sor, I still cannot understand, can you take an example for me, THX

Comment: THX!! I have understood how to use the task scheduling of laravel and success!!